# Remotely disable saved cookies/logins on gmail?

Tags: browser, gmail, cookies, web-application, google-accounts

I just left my job (yay! freedom! money is for suckers) and realized I forgot to clear cookies on my PC. I can call an (ex) coworker and have them do it maybe, but I'd feel safter if it could be turned off somewhere in officially. Is there a way to make it so that the cookies on that computer no longer allow login to Google services? Reddit might be nice, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out in this [Web Applications Stack Exchange answer](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/46198/2356), you can change your Google Account & Reddit passwords to prevent any one else from accessing your accounts from your former office PC.

Answer (score 1):

On a computer (and not mobile device), log into gmail. Once inside, scroll down to the bottom of the page and on the right-hand corner you'll see "Last account activity" and below it the word "Details." Click details and a window will pop up with a tab that says "sign out all other sessions" click that and your done signing out of every location you may be logged in.

Answer (score 0):

you can also view your current logged in device from here:

https://security.google.com/settings/security/activity

=)